# “Shadow is on the surface.”

Tags: prepositions

“Shadow” just means a dark area, but why do we call it “a shadow is ‘on’ the surface,” not “a shadow is a dark surface”?

Comment: Because the shadow covers the surface, it is not the surface itself. Once you take away what blocks the light, the surface remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shadow is not a surface. It isn't anything tangible at all. A shadow is just the effect of a reduction in light caused by blocking a direct light source.

Consider this: if a surface was red, you'd describe it as "a red surface". If a shadow were to cast over it, the perceived shade of red may change slightly, but you would still say it is a red surface.

Remember that we use "on" as a preposition, not only to indicate contact between two things, but also to show the *effect* of something *on* something else. A shadow is not actually in contact with anything, it is just an effect *on* our perception of light and colour. So, referring back to my example, you might say that the red surface has a shadow on (or 'over') it.

Answer (score 0):

Because [shadow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shadow) is the figure that's cast upon a surface by blocking the light. In other words, you need the surface to have a shadow. And the "on" preposition is used to specify which surface the shadow is being casted upon, it doesn't necessarily imply physical contact (see 4 [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/on)).

If there is no surface to be obscured from the light, or thing to cover the light reaching a surface, there is no shadow.